# UTF Encoding for Chinese CharactersJava

Tags: java, encoding, utf

I am receiving a String via an object from an axis webservice. Because I'm not getting the string I expected, I did a check by converting the string into bytes and I get C3A4C2 BDC2A0 C3A5C2 A5C2BD C3A5C2 90C297 in hexa, when I'm expecting E4BDA0 E5A5BD E59097 which is actually 你好吗 in UTF-8.

Any ideas what might be causing 你好吗 to become C3A4C2 BDC2A0 C3A5C2 A5C2BD C3A5C2 90C297? I did a Google search but all I got was a chinese website describing a problem that happens in python. Any insights will be great, thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have what is known as a double encoding.

You have the three character sequence "你好吗" which you correctly point out is encoded in UTF-8 as E4BDA0 E5A5BD E59097.

But now, start encoding each byte of THAT encoding in UTF-8.  Start with E4.  What is *that* codepoint in UTF-8? Try it!  It's C3 A4!

You get the idea.... :-)

Here is a Java app which illustrates this:

```
public class DoubleEncoding {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] encoding1 = "你好吗".getBytes("UTF-8");
        String string1 = new String(encoding1, "ISO8859-1");
        for (byte b : encoding1) {
            System.out.printf("%2x ", b);
        }
        System.out.println();
        byte[] encoding2 = string1.getBytes("UTF-8");
        for (byte b : encoding2) {
            System.out.printf("%2x ", b);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ray, do you have sample coding to produce the problem? I tried    String chinese = new String("你好吗".getBytes("UTF-8"));
   String chineseAgain = new String(chinese.getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(byteArrayToHexString(chineseAgain.getBytes("UTF-8")));
But I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: I can write you one real quick.  But FYI I think I wasn't clear enough.  The E4 which is the first byte in the first UTF encoding is interpreted as a *codepoint*, not a hexstirng, in the second encoding.  Does that help?

Comment: @Maurice I added the concrete example to my answer for you.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Ray! You are a lifesaver, I wanna vote for this but I can't register for some reason. Just a last question. If I receive the C3A4C2 BDC2A0 C3A5C2 A5C2BD C3A5C2 90C297 as a String, what's the proper way to format this back to UTF-8 so I can save 你好吗 into my database as UTF-8?

Comment: Just reverse the steps above: First _parse_ `C3A4C2 BDC2A0 C3A5C2 A5C2BD C3A5C2 90C297` to the byte array `[\xc3, \xa4, \xc2, ...]` then do `new String(byteArray, "UTF-8")` then encode using ISO8859-1 then `new String` that with UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used this and I got the string back.
   String test = new String(encoding2,"UTF-8");
   byte[]test2 = test.getBytes("ISO8859-1");
   System.out.println("Result: " + new String(test2,"UTF-8"));

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Encoder{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     String requestString="你好";
     String ISO = new String(requestString.getBytes("gb2312"), "ISO8859-1");
     String plaintxt = new String(ISO.getBytes("ISO8859-1"), "gb2312");
     plaintxt.getBytes("UTF-8");
    }
}
```