# how can i settext with Chinese charactors In Junit test

Tags: java, junit

i tried to setText"你好"， but it didn't work, do you have any ideas about how to set chinese charactors?

```
        UiObject chatBox = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.tencent.mm:id/z4"));
        if (chatBox.waitForExists(2000)==false) {
            assertFalse("cannot find chatBox option", false);
            return;
        } else {
            chatBox.click();
            chatBox.getSelector().focused(true);
            chatBox.setText("tell me a joke");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use the unicode escape sequences or save your java source files in UTF-8. In the former case, you need to look up the correct escape sequences, in the latter case, you can simply write the Chinese characters in src code. See here for examples [UTF Encoding for Chinese CharactersJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838446/utf-encoding-for-chinese-charactersjava)
If a UI element doesn't correctly display the characters, then the correct font might not be available or used.